# Quotes inside a variable are ignored

Tags: bash

I want to pass an argument to `rsync` from a variable like this:

```
myopts='-e "ssh -p 1234" -a'
rsync $myopts 192.168.0.1:/a /a
```

For some reason this does not work. I even found [this webpage](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting) where it says that it won't work:

```
### NO NO NO: this passes three strings:
###      (1)  "my
###      (2)  multiword
###      (3)  argument"
MYARG="\"my multiword argument\""
somecommand $MYARG

### THIS IS NOT (!!!!) THE SAME AS ###
command "my multiword argument"

### YOU NEED ###
MYARG="my multiword argument"
command "$MYARG"
```

Unfortunately it doesn't say *why* it won't work.

The script containing the `rsync` call is used by a lot of other scripts, so I can only change it in a compatible way. A solutions that doesn't work is using an array:

```
myopts=('-a' '-v' '-z') # new way, would work
myopts='-a -v -z'       # old way, breaks
rsync "${myopts[@]}" 192.168.0.1:/a /a
```

The options from the variable are completely ignored.

Comment: In this particular case, you could use `MYOPTS="-essh -p1234"` and then `rsync "$MYOPTS" 192.168.0.1:/a /a`. In general, though, it's worth learning how to do this right; see the various answers. (I'd go for the array, but YMMV.)

Comment: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After variable expansion, the only processing that's done is word splitting and wildcard expansion (and neither of these is done if the variable is inside doublequotes), not quote processing. You need to use `eval` if you want all steps of command line parsing to be redone:

```
eval "rsync $MYOPTS 192.168.0.1:/a /a"
```

Comment: Actually this solves the problem because changing `rsync $MYOPTS 192.168.0.1:/a /a` to `eval "rsync $MYOPTS 192.168.0.1:/a /a"` does not break the old syntax.

Answer (score 9):

It has to do with the way Bash splits the argument. Now, never, ever put commands and there arguments in one variable. Use arrays instead (and also, stop using uppercase variable names, it's ugly and dangerous as it may clash with already defined variables). You should instead write:

```
myopts=( -e "ssh -p 1234" )
rsync "${myopts[@]}" 192.168.0.1:/a /a
```

In this case, `rsync` will be launched with the following arguments:

```
-e
ssh -p 1234
192.168.0.1:/a
/a
```

which is probably what you want.

---

As to *why* it works this way: assume that

```
myopts='-e "ssh -p 1234"'
```

that is, `myopts` is the following string:

```
-e "ssh -p 1234"
```

Unquoted, Bash will see four tokens. You can check it thus: in a terminal do:

```
$ myopts='-e "ssh -p 1234"'
$ printf 'Token: %s\n' $myopts
Token: -e
Token: "ssh
Token: -p
Token: 1234"
```

so when you launch

```
rsync $myopts 192.168.0.1:/a /a
```

then it's like launching `rsync` with these arguments:

```
-e
"ssh
-p
1234"
192.168.0.1:/a
/a
```

and you probably don't want that `:)`

Now, the variable `$myopts` *quoted*, is just one token:

```
-e "ssh -p 1234"
```

so if you launch (observe the quotes):

```
rsync "$myopts" 192.168.0.1:/a /a
```

it's like launching `rsync` with these arguments:

```
-e "ssh -p 1234"
192.168.0.1:/a
/a
```

and you don't want that either.

Really, the most robust way to solve this problem is to use Bash arrays. Look: define an *array* `myopts` as (do it in a terminal):

```
$ myopts=( -e "ssh -p 1234" )
$ # myopts is an array with two arguments. Check this (observe the quotes):
$ printf "Argument: %s\n" "${myopts[@]}"
Argument: -e
Argument ssh -p 1234
$ # Just for fun, what if we don't quote myopts?
$ printf "Argument: %s\n" ${myopts[@]}
Argument: -e
Argument: "ssh
Argument: -p
Argument 1234"
```

So now, I guess that you understand why this:

```
rsync "${myopts[@]}" 192.168.0.1:/a /a
```

is like launching `rsync` with these arguments:

```
-e
ssh -p 1234
192.168.0.1:/a
/a
```

… and that's probably what you want `:)`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 for the explanation. Unfortunately the proposed solution breaks the scripts that are using the old syntax. I wasn't clear about the way I can change the rsync call, see my updated question.

Comment: Yes.  I think it's unfortunate that bash's array variable syntax is so klunky, but perhaps that's the price of sh compatibility.  (csh's array variables were/are ... differently klunky, but csh itself is just a nightmare for shell script coding.)  This is why I have switched to writing complex scripts in Python. :-)

Comment: @AndreKR If you're programming for Bash, please modify your script so that it handles arrays all the way through for this `myopts`. It's really worth it in the long run! If you read entirely my post, you probably know how to do that safely `:)`.

Comment: Unfortunately not, because `${myopts[@]}` doesn't work with the string. I accepted Barmar's answer because it solves the problem and upvoted yours for the explanation.